# Qual a diferença entre mysql-server e mysql-client?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

É dito que usando o comando `apt-get install mariadb-server` instalaria também o `mariadb-cliente`.

Entendo que o *server* pode se dizer que é onde os dados persistem, entretanto careço de um entendimento sobre o *client*.

---

Ainda se for pertinente, Mysql e Mariadb são o mesmo?

Comment: O cliente serve para você fazer tarefas como sincronizar dois bancos, o local e o em outro servidor, mariadb é um banco criado pelo ex dono do mysql, ele é compatível com mysql, mas não é mysql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## *Server* e *Client*

O pacote do servidor instalará o servidor de banco de dados (Mysql / MariaDB) com o qual você pode interagir usando um cliente. Você pode usar o cliente para enviar comandos para qualquer servidor; em um computador remoto ou o seu próprio computador.

O servidor é usado para persistir os dados e fornecer uma interface de consulta para ele (SQL).

O propósito do cliente é permitir que você use essa interface de consulta. O pacote do cliente também vem com utilitários que permitem *backup* / restauração fácil de dados e administração do servidor.

---

## MariaDB e MySQL

> Ainda se for pertinente, Mysql e Mariadb **são o mesmo**?

Não são o mesmo, eles são muito semelhantes / parecidos e estão sempre sendo *associados*, talvez pelo fato de muito comumente, MariaDB ser referido a uma *continuação* do MySQL e pelo outro fator do banco de dados estar relacionado ao mesmo fundador do MySQL (e ao nome de seus filhos). Existe um número considerável de diferenças entre ambos, além das licenças.

MariaDB é uma [substituição *drop-in* binária compatível com versões anteriores do MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/). O que isso significa é:

> - Arquivos de definição de dados e tabelas (*.frm*) são compatíveis com binários.
> - Todas as *APIs*, protocolos e estruturas do cliente são idênticas.
> - Todos os nomes de arquivos, binários, caminhos, portas, soquetes e etc ... devem ser os mesmos.
> - Todos os conectores MySQL funcionam sem alterações com o MariaDB.
> - O pacote *mysql-client* também funciona com o servidor MariaDB.

Nos cenários práticos mais comuns, MariaDB versão `5.x.y` funcionará exatamente como o MySQL `5.x.y`, já que MariaDB segue a versão do MySQL, ou seja, o número da versão é usado para indicar com qual versão do MySQL é compatível.

MariaDB se originou como um *fork* do MySQL por Michael Monty Widenius, um dos desenvolvedores originais do MySQL e co-fundador do MySQL Ab. A [Fundação MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-foundation/) atua como mantenedora / guardiã do MariaDB.

A principal motivação por parte do MariaDB foi fornecer uma versão [*FLOSS*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-features/) do MySQL, no caso da Oracle se tornar totalmente corporativa com o MySQL. Vale ressaltar que Monty foi [contra a aquisição do MySQL](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/07/05/monty_appeals_ec_oracle_decision/) (via aquisição da Sun) pela Oracle:

> Quero garantir que a base do código MySQL (sob o nome de MariaDB) sobreviverá como *open source*, apesar do que a Oracle possa fazer.[¹](http://www.odbms.org/blog/2011/09/mariadb-the-new-mysql-interview-with-michael-monty-widenius/)

Embora MariaDB seja supostamente compatível com o MySQL, por uma razão ou outra existem [alguns problemas de compatibilidade](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) e [recursos diferentes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-features/):

- MariaDB inclui todos os motores populares de código aberto, não há InnoDB, sendo o [XtraDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-xtradb/) atuante como uma substituição *drop-in*,
- O MariaDB reivindica várias melhorias de velocidade em relação ao MySQL, e
- existem algumas novas extensões *FLOSS* que o MySQL não possui.

MariaDB também afirma ser [SQL99 completo](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/), assim como o MySQL, então não deve haver diferenças nas consultas.

---

#### Curiosidade

Os nomes dos bancos de dados são intimamente relacionados ao nome dos filhos de Monty, um banco para Maria (MariaDB), outro para My (MySQL) e outro para seu filho Max (MaxDB). Que pai faz isso pela suas filhas?

## Fontes

- [What is the difference between MySQL Server and MySQL Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6962890)
- [What's the difference between MariaDB and MySQL?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/120178)

Comment: Boa, bem detalhada :D +1

Answer (score 5):

Enquanto o Mysql-server, é onde fica armazenado os dados, é de fato o banco de dados, o Mysql-client, é para você apenas se conectar, e gerenciar os bancos de dados (mysql-servers), sejam eles locais ou mesmo remotos.

Mariadb, foi criado pelo mesmo criador do MySQL, é um fork o MySQL, por isso existe muita compatibilidade, porém, são SGBDs diferentes